# How do popular websites like Facebook/Twitter/YouTube hide their Control/Admin Panels?

Tags: web, web-development-server

I am currently developing a website that has an Admin / Control Panel which can manage Users, Posts, etc.

My admin panel is located on the website `localhost/admin/login.php`.

I am wondering how do popular websites, like Facebook/YouTube/Twitter/News sites hide their control panels, do they just use external softwares and those pages just don't really exist ON the client side?

Comment: One can only make an educated guess how this is done.  My first guess is that if you are logged in as markzuckerberg, you have access to view all the admin pages.  Otherwise you don't.  It will just kick you back to the home page if you try and access an existing admin page.

Comment: For one of my sites www.example.com has a form users can fill out and it will add to the DB.  I have a page on that site at www.example.com/admin that I only told the admin about.  When you go to it, it simply asks for a password.  If he types in the correct password, it lets him into the admin page to view entries and make changes.

Comment: @dmikester1 I couldn't find any public `www.example.com/admin` pages on Websites like Facebook, Twitter or YouTube which makes me believe they are using external softwares for their content management systems.

Comment: Very possible.  But also, you do not have admin credentials on those sites so their router could be just kicking you to a different page when you try to view it.  Anything is possible...  What are you trying to do in your project?

Comment: A lot of Wordpress admin sites will be www.example.com/wp-admin.php or /admin.php, something like that.  Just pick a URL that wouldn't be easy to guess (admin4982) and password protect it and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

They wont have them, not even on the same domain. 
If you even have a login page for admin exposed to the internet it is possible entry point for hackers. 
It is very likely that all those really big sites that you mentioned have an entirely different system, that's on a private network within the company, that cannot be reached by the public.

Comment: How do you know that's what they do?

Comment: Because I have seen it on many other big companies systems, this is why I think it is so, I made sure I carefully worded my response with 'its very likely' ;)